# Access - salvando dados

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Tenho o código VBA abaixo que salva um novo lançamento.
Ao Fechar o Formulário, mesmo que eu tenha digitado um nome qualquer, ele não é salvo.
Mas notei que automaticamente o Access gera uma nova chave primária, ou seja pula uma chave primária que não será mais utilizada.
Exemplo: se eu tinha até a chave primária 9, ao fechar o formulário o Access irá saltar a chave primária 10, e ao abrir novamente o formulário a próxima chave primária será 11.
É normal ou tem como evitar?

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Me.NomeGrupo.SetFocus
End Sub


Private Sub btSalvar_Click()
    Me.NomeGrupo.SetFocus
    If Me.NomeGrupo.Text = Empty Then
        MsgBox "Operação cancelada!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "O campo Nome do grupo está vazio!", vbInformation, " CADASTRO DE GRUPOS"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If (Not IsNull(DLookup("[NomeGrupo]", "tabGrupos", "[NomeGrupo] ='" & Me!NomeGrupo & "'"))) Then
        MsgBox "Operação cancelada!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "O grupo " & Me.NomeGrupo.Text & " já está cadastrado no sistema!", vbInformation, "CADASTRO DE GRUPO"
        Cancel = True 'cancela o evento.
        Me!NomeGrupo.Undo 'desfaz a digitação.
    Else
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        MsgBox "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!", vbInformation, " CADASTRO DE GRUPOS"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btFechar_Click()
    Me.Undo
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "FormGrupos"
End Sub
```